# How do I use a DIV element for content I want to vertically scroll with the browser's scroll bar?

Tags: jquery, css, browser, scroll

Question:

How can I create a div that is controlled by the browser's scroll bar precisely as the developers of the website below have done with the border effect around the affected element?

--

Example:

http://tinyurl.com/flywheeeel

--

Additional Information

I understand the concept of fixed positioning, element order and overlay manipulation which a curtain reveal effect would depend on, but I can not grasp how to replicate the layout and behavior of the above website. Since the scroll function only becomes available when content flows beyond the viewport area, I can only think an ordered element or background element that exceeds the viewport area is activating the scroll function. Perhaps this thought could explain the trailing form too.

Comment: Why do you think that http://flywheel.co/ has a `div` that's being scrolled? As far as I can tell, it's just `body` with borders added around it.

Comment: have you scrolled all the way down? the content scrolls within the element until it reaches the end and then the element itself scrolls to reveal the trailing form which is all controlled by the browser's scroll bar

Comment: Scroll all the way down and then scroll up just a tiny bit. You'll see that the original bottom border covers up a bit of the "footer."

Comment: It's only confusing because the "footer" section has the same color as the border.

Comment: No worries -- in the future, though, it's good a idea to inspect webpages that have stuff you want to do. Just Google *your browser's name* followed by "inspect web page" to find out how to do that. [Here it is for Chrome, for instance](http://google.com/search?q=chrome+inspect+web+page). Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: I created a test model with body at position fixed, 100% height, 100% width, border 20px solid #333, margin: 0 auto for centering which recreated the appearance of the website above. But when I added a block level element (paragraph) with overflow: auto applied to html body and the only scrollbar appearing is the one in the paragraph element itself which is likely being inherited from body and html. this is one of the problems i was having earlier. none of the content or elements are actually exceeding the viewport area. so there is no browser scrollbar appearing.

Comment: Please close this question and create another question to get help with that specific issue.

Comment: Hope this fiddle helps: http://jsfiddle.net/nejo/LVdh9/1/